# Behaviour of member functions when forward declaring classes

Tags: c++, class, c++11, forward-declaration

When the following code is compiled with C++11, it behaves as expected.

```
class Student;

class University
{
    vector <Student*> students;
public:
    University();
    void print();
};

class Student
{
    string name;
public:
    Student(string nom) : name(nom) {}
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, Student* S)
    {
        return out << S -> name;
    }
};

University::University()
{
    for (string name: {"Alice", "Bob"})
        students.push_back(new Student(name));
}

void University::print() { for (auto s: students) cout << s << '\n'; }

int main()
{
    University uni;
    uni.print();
}
```

The printout is

```
Alice
Bob
```

However, when the print() function is implemented inside its class declaration like this:

```
class University
{
    vector <Student*> students;
public:
    University();
    void print() { for (auto s: students) cout << s << '\n'; }
};
```

The printout becomes

```
0x20055ff0
0x20056028
```

**Question**: Why does the `print()` function behave like this even though `Student` has been declared in the very first line?

**Solution**: Declare all classes before implementing any of their member functions. So long as `print()` and `operator <<` are both implemented after their classes' declaration, `print()` will work correctly even if it's implemented before `operator <<`

Comment: As a general rule I would say it is better to write operator << overloads on references to your objects, rather than pointers. You would have then got an error that there was no operator<< for your object.

Comment: @GemTaylor If I write `operator <<` overloads on `Student&` then `print()` will print out hex addresses; there will be no compile error. Unfortunately I must use `Student*` because `vector <Student&>` in the `University` class would be a compile error.

Comment: But you could write `cout << *s `. To be honest using raw pointers like this is its own nightmare, because you now have to remember to delete them as well in your destructor.

Comment: I accept your `cout << *s` recommendation, but is there a way to avoid raw pointers like `Student*` when `vector` cannot hold references? I can't have `vector <Student>` either since I don't want `Student`s to be deleted when a `University` is deleted.

Comment: Sadly you are very limited. You could use smart pointers such as std::shared_ptr and std::unique_ptr, but again they require the definition of the Student class in order to be defined - and then you might as well use a vector of Student instances. If Student was an interface base class, then you would be justified in requiring the interface base class to be defined before it is used.

Comment: You could define a unique_ptr with a custom destroy argument that you haven't defined yet. Surprise: when you do define it, when Student is defined, it just does a default delete. You could simply write your own wrapper class round Student* that has a destructor. Both these contract you to actually write the code to delete the instances.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default behavior of printing a pointer with `operator<<` is to print the hex representation of the memory address being pointing at.

When the implementation of `print()` is inside the class declaration, the compiler has not yet seen the `operator<<` override for a `Student*` pointer, so it doesn't know that it should behave any differently than the default.

When you define the `print()` implementation after the `operator<<` override, the compiler knows to use that override instead of the default.

Comment: If you really want to you can forward declare your class and your operator<< so that they can be seen by inline methods.